# image button beside each record in a grid

Tags: asp.net, grid

iam working on asp.net &c#

i am working on the following scenario.

i have two records ajay and mike in a grid.

requirement:i need a image button to be displayed beside their names such that on clicking the button it will have common functionality for both records.

if i click on the button beside ajay it displays a div with all hyperlinks of ajay

if i click on the button beside mike it displays a div with all hyperlinks of mike

also the button should not be displyed for all the records,it should be displayed only for particular users

can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageButton with TemplateFields to achieve this.

```
<asp:GridView id="gridview" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick='OpenDiv(); return false;' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       function OpenDiv(){
          // do whatever here to open div based on the id
          return false;
       }

    </script>
```

Comment: but i do want to show the button only for certain records but how can i do that?
i was just able to get up to onrowdatabound evenyt,and was struck in h functionality of showing the imagebutton fro the particular user

Comment: in the rowdatabound event, just do a 
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")
btn.Visible = false

Comment: thank u wil,i was able to get that?,
also  Wil, iam just adding the alt text for the image in the rowdatabound event ?
 is it possible for me to retreive the alt text at the mouse over event ?